# Can I use SFTP as SCP?

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp

My client wants a simple storage accessible via SCP and SFTP. There will be two user accounts, one is read-only and the other is read-write.

For security reasons I want to dumb it down as much as possible:

1. I want the user to be restricted to their home directory without a way to get out
2. User's root directory must remain writable. SSH's internal-sftp with chroot unfortunately fails this one
3. I don't want to allow any access to a normal shell
4. I don't want users to be able to mess with permissions/owners of the files

So far I have implemented SFTP using SSH + MySecureShell, it works and it seems pretty bulletproof. However, SCP does not work, which was one of the requirements of my client.

1. Is there any way to make SCP work with MySecureShell? Or some other shell?
2. If not, is there some way to use sftp from a command line like you would scp? I mean, not interactively and using syntax as close to SCP as possible.

Answer (score 6):

In the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` change the SFTP subsystem type:

```
Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp
```

This allows to perform all the filesystem operations without any shell. 
Then change the user's shell in the `passwd` file to the `/bin/true` or something else harmless. Ensure added "shell" is mentioned in the `/etc/shells` as legal binary allowed to be used as shell.

Also you can restrict users by `chroot` feature of the `internal-sftp`.

```
Match                   User alice 
  X11Forwarding         no
  AllowTcpForwarding    no
  ChrootDirectory       /some/place/alicedir
```

Directories `some`, `place` and `alicedir` should be owned by `root` and should not be writable by anyone except `root`. Directory `alicedir` should contain  directories like `upload`, `htdocs` or else that should be owned by `alice` with rwx------/700 permissions.